# Python, курсор фоновой загрузки

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

У меня есть python скрипт который, каждые 0,5 секунд,  фоново(через pythonw), запускается внешней программой. Проблема в том что при каждом запуске, курсор меняется на курсор с загрузкой, возможно ли как-то этого избежать?

Comment: Насколько знаю, курсора с загрузкой не избежать. Хотя можно попытаться в настройках курсора винды сделать так, чтобы вообще не появлялся курсор с загрузкой.

Comment: Спасибо, эта идея мне первой в голову пришла, но скрипт планируется под широкую аудиторию, поэтому таких радикальных мер хотелось бы избежать.

Comment: значит придется терпеть этот курсор

Comment: А внешняя программа - на питоне?